# Solved : updating data in Mongodb via React JS (backend in Express) not working

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

//Update 2 : An embarassing mistake in my Edit.js file where i am doing the patch request. the $ sign for the id in the patch request should be outside the curly braces, i had put it inside. I have updated the code in the OG post and this is working smooth now.

//Update > I am able to access the specific id now however my patch request is not working. Can someone guide me Please. Updated the title of the issue and the code below.

// I am trying to Edit a specific document in MongoDB via my React UI. Currently whatever item I click to edit, the  auto filled data shows the value for the first document of the collection. Please guide me on how can I fetch the specific id of that document where I am clicking. The backend API is working fine (checked in Postman). Facing issue while integrating with frontend.

**DashBoard.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import Header from './Header';
import List from './List';
import Edit from './Edit';
import client from '../axioscalls/api'


function Dashboard() {

    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
    const [selectedEmployee, setSelectedEmployee] = useState(null);
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

 const handleEdit = (id) => {
        const [employee] = employees.filter(employee => employee._id === id);
        console.log("Printing handle edit" +employee)
        setSelectedEmployee(employee);
        setIsEditing(true);
    }
    

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {/* List */}
            {!isAdding && !isEditing && (
                <>
                    <Header
                    />
                    <List
                        employees={employees}
                        handleEdit={handleEdit}
                       
                    />
                </>
            )}
          
            {/* Edit */}
            {isEditing && (
                <Edit
                    employees={employees}
                    selectedEmployee={selectedEmployee}
                    setEmployees={setEmployees}
                    setIsEditing={setIsEditing}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**List.js**

```
 import React from 'react'

function List({ employees, handleEdit}) {
    return (
        <div className='contain-table'>
            <table className='striped-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>SERIAL NUMBER</th>
                        <th>MONGODBID</th>
                        <th>FIRSTNAME</th>
                        <th>LASTNAME</th>
                        <th>EMAILADDRESS</th>
                        <th>EMPID</th>
                        <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                        <th>DOB</th>
                        <th colSpan={2} className="text-center">
                            Actions
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {employees.length > 0 ? (
                        employees.map((employee, i) => (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td>{i+1}</td>
                                <td>{employee._id}</td>
                                <td>{employee.FIRSTNAME}</td>
                                <td>{employee.LASTNAME}</td>
                                <td>{employee.EMAILADDRESS}</td>
                                <td>{employee.EMPID}</td>
                                <td>{employee.DEPARTMENT} </td>
                                <td>{employee.DOB} </td>
                                <td className="text-right">
                                    <button
                                        onClick={() => handleEdit(employee.id)}
                                        className="button muted-button"
                                    >
                                        Edit
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan={9}>No Employees</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List
```

**Edit js**

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import client from '../axioscalls/api'

function Edit({ employees, selectedEmployee, setEmployees, setIsEditing }) {

    const id = selectedEmployee._id;

    const [FIRSTNAME, setFIRSTNAME] = useState(selectedEmployee.FIRSTNAME);
    const [LASTNAME, setLASTNAME] = useState(selectedEmployee.LASTNAME);
    const [EMAILADDRESS, setEMAILADDRESS] = useState(selectedEmployee.EMAILADDRESS);
    const [EMPID, setEMPID] = useState(selectedEmployee.EMPID);
    const [DEPARTMENT, setDEPARTMENT] = useState(selectedEmployee.DEPARTMENT);
    const [DOB, setDOB] = useState(selectedEmployee.DOB);

      const handleUpdate = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!FIRSTNAME || !LASTNAME || !EMAILADDRESS || !EMPID || !DEPARTMENT || !DOB) {
            return Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Error!',
                text: 'All fields are required.',
                showConfirmButton: true
            });
        }
    
        const updatedmployee = {
            id,
            FIRSTNAME : FIRSTNAME,
            LASTNAME : LASTNAME,
            EMAILADDRESS : EMAILADDRESS,
            EMPID : EMPID,
            DEPARTMENT : DEPARTMENT,
            DOB : DOB
        };
        console.log("Printing from Edit" +updatedmployee)
        client
        .patch(`/api/update/${id}`,updatedmployee)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          console.log("Printing before if from Edit.js" +employees);
          for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i]._id === id) {
                employees.splice(i, 1, updatedmployee);
                console.log("Printing inside if from Edit.js" +employees);
                break;
            }
        }
        setEmployees(employees);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
        setIsEditing(false);
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Updated!',
            text: `${updatedmployee.FIRSTNAME} ${updatedmployee.LASTNAME}'s data has been updated.`,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
        });
    }
    return (
        <div className="small-container">
            <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
                <h1>Edit Employee</h1>
                <label htmlFor="FIRSTNAME">First Name</label>
                <input
                    id="FIRSTNAME"
                    type="text"
                    name="FIRSTNAME"
                    value={FIRSTNAME}
                    onChange={e => setFIRSTNAME(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="LASTNAME">Last Name</label>
                <input
                    id="LASTNAME"
                    type="text"
                    name="LASTNAME"
                    value={LASTNAME}
                    onChange={e => setLASTNAME(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="EMAILADDRESS">Email</label>
                <input
                    id="EMAILADDRESS"
                    type="email"
                    name="EMAILADDRESS"
                    value={EMAILADDRESS}
                    onChange={e => setEMAILADDRESS(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="EMPID">EMPID</label>
                <input
                    id="EMPID"
                    type="number"
                    name="EMPID"
                    value={EMPID}
                    onChange={e => setEMPID(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="DEPARTMENT">DEPARTMENT</label>
                <input
                    id="DEPARTMENT"
                    type="text"
                    name="DEPARTMENT"
                    value={DEPARTMENT}
                    onChange={e => setDEPARTMENT(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label htmlFor="DOB">DOB</label>
                <input
                    id="DOB"
                    type="date"
                    name="DOB"
                    value={DOB}
                    onChange={e => setDOB(e.target.value)}
                />
                <div style={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                    <input
                        style={{ marginLeft: '12px' }}
                        className="muted-button"
                        type="button"
                        value="Cancel"
                        onClick={() => setIsEditing(false)}
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Edit
```

**Controller : emp.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const EmployeeData = require('../Models/empdata')


    async function UpdateOneEmployee(req,res,next){

    try {
      const id = req.params.id
      const updates = req.body
      const options = {new: true} ;
      const result = await EmployeeData.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updates,options);
      res.send(result);


    } catch(error) {
      console.log("Error in fetching data using id" +error.message)
    }
}
module.exports = {UpdateOneEmployee}
```

**router : empdata.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const {UpdateOneEmployee} = require('../Controller/emp')

const router = express.Router()

 router.patch('/update/:id',UpdateOneEmployee)


module.exports = router;
```

**Model : empdata.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const empschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    FIRSTNAME :{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    LASTNAME :{
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    EMAILADDRESS : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    EMPID : {
        type: Number,
        required : true,
        unique: true
    },
    DEPARTMENT : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    DOB : {
        type : Date
        
    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model("PatternEmployeeData", empschema)
```

Comment: Where you are calling the Client api in react ?

Comment: I am confused about whether i should call it in Dashboard.js or List.js.

Comment: The current piece of handledit code is from when i was picking the data from a text file. Now that i have connected to db i want to modify this method accordingly.

Comment: Apologies, i had missed adding Edit.js code. I have resolved my previous query ( I was incorrectly accessing id of the document via employee.id however the correct approach would be employee._id  ) however my patch request is not working. Can someone guide me please. I have updated the code and the title of the question

Comment: what was the error displayed when u call the patch api ?

Comment: I am getting this :
 Error in fetching data using idCast to ObjectId failed for value "{$id}" (type string) at path "_id" for model
on my server side.

Comment: I saw the workarounds which says to use findByIdAndUpdate but i am already using that in my Controller .
Can you guide me towards the path where i might have gone wrong.

Comment: It seems i am not able to pass the id correctly to the patch request.

Comment: I am embarassed at all levels for the silly mistake that i did. the $ sign for id variable should be outside curly braces. I had put it inside. This might have been caused by the late night coding.

I have updated the code :

Before :
client
        .patch(`/api/update/{$id}`,updatedmployee)

After :
client
        .patch(`/api/update/${id}`,updatedmployee)